# Chrome incorrect z-axis order with translate3d

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In the following HTML/CSS there are three boxes; one red, one blue and one yellow. If you mouse over the blue box, it is translated towards the user in the z-axis with the CSS `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 5px)`. This should mean the blue box is drawn in front of the yellow and red box.

#### HTML

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    margin: 20px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;

    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#blue:hover {           
    -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
    transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0w3gho9/5/)

#### Firefox

Behaves as expected

[image: firefox]

#### Chrome

Does NOT behave as expected. The yellow box is drawn in front!

[image: chrome]

Is this a bug? Is there a work around? How can I fix this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0w3gho9/5/)?

Comment: You can work around it with [`z-index`](http://jsfiddle.net/p0w3gho9/6/), but I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I tried working around with `z-index`, but it was the `position: relative;` that I was missing. If you post as an answer, I will accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested :)

It seems Chrome ignores the **z** value of transformations when it renders a page, instead reverting to the [Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) (what is defined first is drawn first).  You can get around this by forcing the `#blue` div to have a greater `z-index` than its siblings, and giving each sibling `position: relative` to make the changes take effect:

```
#red, #yellow, #blue {
    position: relative;
}

#red, #yellow {
    z-index: 2;
}

#blue {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `z-index` solution (by Scott) is a much better solution, but this is an alternate one with an explanation of why it occurs this way:

`#blue` is in it's own composited layer (when you hover over it/and/or it is transitioning) compared to `#yellow` and `#red`. You could simply add a container and add a transformation which places `#blue`, `#yellow`, and `#red` in the same composited layer at which point the expected effect (where transformation along the `z` axis actually places an element **in front**) will be respected:

**EDIT**
This answer does have the added advantage that now the `z-index` (or, whichever element is *on top*) will be the element that has the higher z translation (hover over the blue or yellow divs).

```css
/* place .container (and descendents) in the same composited layer */
.container {
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

div {
    margin: 20px;
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    
    -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* now you can see that whatever has the higher z translation will appear in front */
#yellow:hover,
#blue:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
    transform: perspective(10px) translate3d(0, 0, 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say this answer is much better, I didn't even think of looking at the layers.  Nice work!

Comment: @ScottKaye - it's actually not, because you're promoting `#blue`, `#yellow`, and `#red` to be rendered on the GPU (more memory), when they don't need to be. Developers should be careful to promote layers to the GPU only when absolutely necessary, because it does come at a cost.